# Insertar elemento a un array Javascript

Tags: array

HAy algun metodo para insertar un elemento a un array indicando la posicion en donde quiero que se inserte?

Ejemplo: array.insert(1,5) #seria sintaxis python, le digo que agregue a array el numero 5 en pos 1

hay un meotod asi en js?

Comment: ¿Qué has averiguado o intentado? ¿Has buscado la documentación del objeto `Array` para saber los métodos de los que dispone?

Answer (score 0):

Si hay uno. El método [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) te permite insertar un elemento en un índice concreto.

**Por ejemplo**:

```
arr.splice(2, 0, "Elemento")
```

En el enlace de arriba te dejo la guía. Esta duda ya ha sido resuelta en otro post. Te dejo el enlace al post para que te sirva de referencia.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586182/how-to-insert-an-item-into-an-array-at-a-specific-index-javascript

Puedes encontrar más ejemplos e información acerca de javascript en esta [página](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Espero que te sirva de ayuda